# Javascript timestamp grouped by X minutes

Tags: javascript, arrays, timestamp

I want to create timestamp list grouped by X minutes.

For instance I have min data value and max date timestamp value.

```
minDate = 1524548466000; // Tuesday, April 24, 2018 5:41:06 AM
maxDate = 1524577986000; // Tuesday, April 24, 2018 1:53:06 PM
```

So I want to create timestamp array start with *Tuesday, April 24, 2018 5:40:0 AM* to *Tuesday,April 24, 2018, 1:55:00 PM* using javascript.

I want this output:

*[1524548400000,1524548700000,1524549000000,...1524578100000]*

How can I do this?

Comment: Use `Date()` and its methods `setMinutes()` & `getMinutes()`

Comment: thanks for your comment but they keep changing, not static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if duration is 5 min then you can set duration variable as follows.

```
var duration = 5 * 60 * 1000;
endTime = endTime - endTime % duration;
startTime = startTime - startTime % duration;

for(var i=startTime;i<endTime;i+=duration){
     arr.push(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. I just count second and compare with maxDate.

```js
var minDate = new Date(1524548466000); // Tuesday, April 24, 2018 5:41:06 AM
var maxDate = new Date(1524577986000); // Tuesday, April 24, 2018 1:53:06 PM
var listTimestamp = [];
while (minDate.getTime() !== maxDate.getTime()) {
  minDate.setSeconds(minDate.getSeconds() + 1);
  listTimestamp.push(minDate.getTime());
}
console.log(listTimestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the function you needed

```js
function timestampGrouping(minDate, maxDate, x){
    var gap = x * 60000 //60000 = 1minute;
    minDate = Math.floor(minDate/gap)*gap;
    maxDate = Math.ceil(maxDate/gap)*gap;

    var arr = [];

    while(minDate <= maxDate){
        arr.push(minDate);
        minDate += gap;
    }
    return arr;
}

var groupingArr = timestampGrouping(1524548466000, 1524577986000, 5);
console.log(groupingArr);
```

`Math.floor` and `Math.ceil` is to find the nearest gap value you required, and just loop thought the value to get all the minute gap you want.

***minDate, maxDate and gap value can be anything you wish to.***

Hope this is what you required.

Answer (score 0):

You could divide the given [Unix Time (Epoch Time)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) and divide it by a product of wanted minutes, seconds and 1000 for miliseconds.

```
5 minutes * 60 seconds * 1000 milliseconds = 300000
```

For moving events in the same slot use

```
Math.floor(time / 300000)
```